# Kohana (KO3) columns with ORM join

Tags: orm, join, kohana

I'm trying to retrieve information from a database using Kohana ORM.

There are two relevant tables in my database:

**branches**

```
    id          smallint
    parent_id   smallint
    name        varchar
    active      int
```

**branches_options**

```
    id          mediumint
    branche_id  smallint
    name        varchar
    customer_id int
```

With the following code I want to retrieve the information from the branches_options table

```
`    $branchesOptions[] = ORM::factory('branches_option')
        ->where('branche_id', '=', $subBranche)
        ->join('branches', 'LEFT')->on('branches.id', '=', 'branches_options.branche_id')
        ->order_by('name')
        ->find_all()
        ->as_array();`
```

Now I want to see the value of branches.name in the result set, but I'm not sure how to do this in Kohana.

The code of the models is:

```
    `class Model_Branche extends ORM
     {
        protected $_has_many = array( 
            "options" => array('model' => 'branches_option'),
            "adwords_templates" => array ('model' => 'adwords_template')
        );

        public $result = array();`
```

and

```
    `class Model_Branches_option extends ORM
     {
        protected $_has_many = array ( 
            "keywords" => array('model' => 'branches_options_keyword')
        );

        protected $_has_and_belongs_to = array (
            "adwords_templates" => array (
                "model" => "adwords_template", 
                "through" => "branches_options_templates"
            )
        );

        protected $_belongs_to = array ( "branche" => array () );`
```

Can this be done and if so, how?

Comment: Can you post the code of your models, please? Did you define the relations between them properly?

Comment: Edited my question to add the models.

Comment: What are these arrays? `array('model' => 'branches_options_keyword')
        );` Please post your code properly. And what is `$_has_and_belongs_to`? Kohanas ORM does not have that option.

Comment: It seems part of my code got lost.

Comment: I'm not that well know with Kohana, I will remove / correct the `$_has_and_belongs_to` part. It looks a bit like KO2 code that should not be there.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make some important changes to you models for this to work properly:

```
class Model_Branche extends ORM
{
    protected $_has_many = array( 
        'options' => array(
            'model' => 'branches_option',
            'foreign_key' => 'branche_id'
        )
    );
}
```

And the Branches_Option model (it should be in `model/branche/` folder):

```
class Model_Branches_Option extends ORM
{
    protected $_belongs_to = array(
        'branche' => array()
    );
}
```

Now you can do something like that:

```
$options = ORM::factory('branche', $branche_id)
    ->options
    ->find_all();

foreach ($options as $option)
{
    $branche_active = $option->branche->active;
    $branche_name = $option->branch->name;
    $option_name = $option->name;
}
```

One of the most important changes here is that we specify the `foreign_key` option in the `$_has_many` relationship. Since the ORM is using the **Kohana Inflector** helper it might not recognize it automatically (***branches*** in singular form is ***branch*** and not ***branche***).

If it doesn't work try specifying the `$_table_name` property for the same reason.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to also grasp the concept here. In order to think like an ORM in this regard, you need to start with tables that the main tables reference as related information.

So in my world, I have a waste report, (model/waste/report) and there exists another table that has all the codes (model/waste/codes). so in the waste_reports table there's a column called code. That field might have 2E. 2E means nothing without the waste_codes table. The waste_codes table is (id, code, name).

I defined this relationship as such:

```
class Model_Waste_code extends ORM {

    protected $_primary_key = "code";

    protected $_has_one = array(
        'waste_report' => array()
    );
}
```

Then in my waste report model:

```
class Model_Waste_report extends ORM
{
    protected $_belongs_to = array(
        'codes' => array(
            'model' => 'waste_code',
            'foreign_key' => 'code'
        )
    ); 
}
```

To show different examples:

```
public function action_ormwaste() {
    $test = ORM::factory('waste_report',76);
    if ($test->loaded())
        echo $test->codes->name;

    echo "<hr noshade />";

    $test = ORM::factory('waste_report')->find_all();
    foreach($test as $row)
        echo $row->codes->name . "<BR>";

}
```

Would output:

```
Error with image file (mirrored, etc)
-------------------------------------
Wrong Size
Extra Prints
Error with image file (mirrored, etc)
etc...
```

So in essense, the join on the data is handled on the fly. I'm using Kohana 3.2.

Thanks, that cleared me up.